# Regex to allow only 1-31 numbers and disable letters & symbols

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am using this regex for DayDate input=type[text]

```
^(0?[1-9]|[1@2][0-9]|3[01])$
```

I want to disable the option to enter letters which in my case users can.

I cant use input=type[number]

I found that `\D` is to allow only digits in the regex, but not sure where to place it in mine regex mentioned above

Comment: What is `[1@2]` supposed to be?

Comment: \D means non-digit characters

Comment: Your _expression_ does not allow letters. (It allows `@2`, but that is due to your incorrect pattern in that place.) But these patterns are applied when the form is checked for validity only, they do not prevent that the user _enters_ any “disallowed” characters in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe it does not allow letters, yes. But yet it does! Not sure why...
So i wanted to make sure that it doesnt allow letters at all with adding the non-digit character expression "\D" in the expression above

Comment: No, your _pattern_ does not allow letters. Wether or not your _input field_ allows to type them in in the first place, is a completely different issue. That depends on _how_ you are actually “applying” that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[1-9]$|^[1-2][0-9]$|^3[0-1]$
```

This will match:

- A single digit between 1-9;
- Either a 1 or a 2 followed by anything between 0-9, to match 10 to 29;
- A 3 followed by either a 0 or a 1, to capture 30 and 31.

But regular expressions aren't really meant for this sort of thing. If you have any way of doing numerical validation instead, please do it. It's infinitely easier and more efficient to just check if $num > 0 and <= 31.

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand `\d` can be used instead of `[0-9]`.
It's just a slightly shorter version.

While the shorthand `\d` can be used to find "a number" (from 0 to 9), `\D` is the exact opposite representing everything that is "*not* a number".

Using `\d` you could rewrite your regex to `^(0?[1-9]|[1@2]\d|3[01])$` with no impact on the result.

Resource: https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html